# Getting error when installing DIGImend from dkms

Tags: dkms

I recently tried to Install DIGImend following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHEGahVIoc) in order to use keys of huion h950p. But When I tried

```
sudo make dkms_install
```

It gives me this error:

```
dkms add .

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/source ->
                 /usr/src/digimend-10

DKMS: add completed.
dkms build digimend/10

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-59-generic KVERSION=5.8.0-59-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/digimend-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-59-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build/make.log for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:74: dkms_modules_install] Error 10
```

### Here is the make.log file

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build'
make -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-59-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-59-generic'
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:17: scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h] Error 127
make[3]: *** [Makefile:633: syncconfig] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:738: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-59-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build'
```

I couldn't manage to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `flex` and `bison` packages?

Comment: Yes I tried. Then encounter same problem, [here](https://pastebin.com/e2bLQ1CN). @steeldriver. Even I tried to upgrade dkms `sudo apt-get install -y dkms` but encounter same issue.

Comment: I guess I installed from `.deb` few weeks ago then uninstall it. Because my stylus was not detect. After uninstall it, the problem was fixed. Then I tried this procedure, now I am here.

Comment: If the package is installed, but the bison program is not found then you may need to reinstall it (`sudo apt install --reinstall bison`)

Comment: When I try to install or reinstall bison/flex, getting 
`Setting up digimend-dkms (10) ...
Removing old digimend-10 DKMS files...
` error. Why was that? @steeldriver. Seems nothing can be done until fixing `digimend-dkms`